# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS populating cell contents in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, exc-bad-access

I'm struggling to get my head around an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error that I'm getting. The code is as follows:

```
// Update the cell
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell // crash here
   cell.image.image = image
   if(collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0) > indexPath.row) {
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
   }               
})
```

The code is designed to asynchronously fill in an image in a collectionViewCell after receiving a response from a NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest.

The crash is happening on the `let cell =` line, because (I believe) the indexPath no longer exists (because I've changed the contents on the collectionView). I'm not sure how to check that though.

I thought something along the lines of `if let cell =` would work, but I think I'd misunderstood how that works. And from reading other posts, I can see that you can't put the code in a try/catch block either.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing this in `cellForRow...`? you should do that there

Comment: Yes - this is just a small part of that. The idea being that the rows will display, and then the images in them will be asynchronously filled in, so that scrolling etc. is smooth.

Comment: ok, but why are you doing this inside: `let cell = ....`?

Comment: and maybe use some library like https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for async image downloading....

Comment: paste full code written in cellForRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` is used to reuse cells in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` instead of creating them manually. What you want here is to retrieve the cell, not to reuse it, so you should use: `cellForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath)`.

Comment: Sorted - `if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? RewardCollectionViewCell {` - thanks for your help!